Selenium standalone test in one docker container
I am adding a step to the CI/CD pipeline that we have to test the company portal. For that, I need to run some static selenium tests. I am running into an issue of

WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

It seems that the problem is with the driver, and even though I am running my tests in headless mode with no GPU, I still have this problem.
I know that I would need a driver to run these tests, like this, but it requires a local host running a selenium server container. My question is that how can I make a single, isolated docker container to run my selenium tests, without docker-compose?
Any minimal combination of the test.py, Dockerfile is appreciated.
Thanks.

You can refer this repo where I just tried to execute simple test in github actions with dockerfile.
Additional note : I faced chrome crashing error when I passed headless and disable gpu but after passing no-sandbox option, issue not occurred.
You can check with Actions run details in same repo
